# encountered many times this difficulty of decimal in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, ddl

I encountered many times this problem of decimal in MySQL !

When i put this type: `DECIMAL(10,8)`

The maximum value allowed are: `99.99999999` !

It supposed to be: `9999999999.99999999` no ?

I want a maximum value of decimal with 8 digits after the point (.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html):

> The declaration syntax for a DECIMAL column is DECIMAL(M,D). The ranges of values for the arguments in MySQL 5.7 are as follows:
>
> - M is the maximum number of digits (the precision). It has a range of 1 to 65.
> - D is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point (the scale). It has a range of 0 to 30 and must be no larger than M.

The first value is not the number of digits to the left of the decimal point, but the total number of digits.

That's why the value `9999999999.99999999` with `DECIMAL(10, 8)` is not possible: it is 18 digits long.

Comment: First thank's for your comment and precisions, and how i can resolve the problem ? what is the solution ?

Comment: If you really want to have a precision of 8 digits at the right of the decimal point, then D must be at least 8. Then, you have to figure out the maximum value you will have to handle, and calculate M accordingly. `DECIMAL(18, 8)` would be able to handle `9999999999.99999999` correctly for instance. Using the `float` type might also be a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

A `decimal` is defined by two parameters - `DECIMAL(M, D)`, where `M` is the total number of digits, and `D` is number of digits after the decimal point **out of `M`**. To properly represent the number `9999999999.99999999`, you'd need to use `DECIMAL(18, 8)`.

Answer (score 1):

The way `DECIMAL(x,y)` specifiers work is `x` represents the total number of digits and `y` the number that come after the decimal place.

10,8 means NN.NNNNNNNN.

If you want more, you need to make your range larger accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The first number is the total of digits, and the second one is the number of decimal places.

For the number you request, try `DECIMAL(18,8)`.

Answer (score 0):

You define DECIMAL(total positions, total decimal) so remember: the total decimal use the positions of the total positions, if you want most numbers to left and to right, use FLOAT type.